# Passing innerHTML value of ID as the ("string") reference for getSheetByName()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I making a schedule app with pages for each day of the week. There are pages for Mon-Fri.
Each page pulls info from their corresponding sheet also labeled Mon-Fri.

So page "Monday" and it's functions should pull from the "Monday" sheet/tab... easy enough.

**The simple solution...**

Just use `getSheetByName("Monday")` on the Monday page, "Tuesday" for Tuesday, etc.

Yes this works, **BUT** I have multiple functions to run for each page. Meaning I will have to duplicate any current or future functions by 5 in order to satisfy each page/day of the week. So 8 function multiplied by 5 days now means 40 functions. I want to avoid this.

**The problem...**

I'm want to pass the innerHTML of an ID as the sheet/tab name inside getSheetByName(**here**).

Monday for my example -- I simply need the innerHTML of id=dayofweek "Monday" to be injected into getSheetByName(**here**)

This way I don't have to make multiple groups of the same functions for each day of the week.

**The HTML...**

```
<title id="dayofweek">Monday</title>
```

**Monday page script...**

```
<script>

var theDay = document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML;
Console.log(theDay);

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateMondayDate).getDate();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateMondayShift).getShift();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateMondayDur).getDur();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateMondayNaps).getNaps();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateMondayClean).getClean();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateMondaySupport).getSupport();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateMondayAllClient).getAllClient();
        
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
        var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems);

});

function generateMonday(dataArray) {

    var tbody = document.getElementById("shift-overview-section");

    dataArray.forEach(function (r) {

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var col1 = document.createElement("td");
        col1.textContent = r[0];
        var col2 = document.createElement("td");
        col2.textContent = r[1];
        var col3 = document.createElement("td");
        col3.textContent = r[2];
        var col4 = document.createElement("td");
        col4.textContent = r[3];
        var col5 = document.createElement("td");
        col5.textContent = r[4];
        var col6 = document.createElement("td");
        col6.textContent = r[5];

        row.appendChild(col1);
        row.appendChild(col2);
        row.appendChild(col3);
        row.appendChild(col4);
        row.appendChild(col5);
        row.appendChild(col6);

        tbody.appendChild(row);

    });

}

function generateMondayDur(dataArray) {
//Inject stuff I get from getDur() in functions.js
}
function generateMondayNaps(dataArray) {
//Inject stuff I get from getNaps() in functions.js
}
function generateMondayClean(dataArray) {
//Inject stuff I get from getClean() in functions.js
}
function generateMondaySupport(dataArray) {
//Inject stuff I get from getSupport() in functions.js
}
function generateMondayAllClient(dataArray) {
//Inject stuff I get from getAllClient () in functions.js
}
 
</script>
```

`Console.log(theDay);` shows that the correct info and typeof for "Monday". I just can't seem to inject this value correctly into the functions.js page

**My functions.js...**

```
var user = Session.getActiveUser();

function getDate() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(masterUrl);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName(theDay); // "Monday" = document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML;
  var data = ws.getRange(X,X,X,X).getDisplayValues();

var filteredData = data.filter(function (employee) { return employee[0]  === currentUser; })
 
Console.log(data);

  return filteredData;
}

function getShift() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(masterUrl);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName(theDay); // "Monday" = document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML;
  var data = ws.getRange(X,X,X,X).getDisplayValues();
 
Console.log(data);

  return data;
}
function getDur() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(masterUrl);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName(theDay); // "Monday" = document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML;
  var data = ws.getRange(X,X,X,X).getDisplayValues();
 
Console.log(data);

  return data;
}
function getNaps() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(masterUrl);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName(theDay); // "Monday" = document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML;
  var data = ws.getRange(X,X,X,X).getDisplayValues();
 
Console.log(data);

  return data;
}
function getClean() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(masterUrl);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName(theDay); // "Monday" = document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML;
  var data = ws.getRange(X,X,X,X).getDisplayValues();
 
Console.log(data);

  return data;
}
function getSupport() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(masterUrl);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName(theDay); // "Monday" = document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML;
  var data = ws.getRange(X,X,X,X).getDisplayValues();
 
Console.log(data);

  return data;
}
function getAllClient() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(masterUrl);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName(theDay); // "Monday" = document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML;
  var data = ws.getRange(X,X,X,X).getDisplayValues();
 
Console.log(data);

  return data;
}
```

Log shows the ID is "Monday" and the typeof is a indeed a string, but I'm just too novice when it comes to passing "theDay" variable from my page script to my functions.js.

Comment: Why don't you just let the Date().getDay()  determine the sheet name and use and array like let wday = ['Sunday","Monday"...etc] and the select the sheet by the current day of the week.  Then you don't need many functions. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)  This is not that hard of a problem.  Think about it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I tried making something along the lines of "gather the current date", but then the current day propagates for every day of the week. So if today is Friday... every page(day of the week) I visit grabs today = Friday. This is why I want to use the ID of the page to determing the tab to grab. I agree it has to be simple. It really seems that way, but I haven't been able to solve it. Which is odd because I can easily do more complicated things like gathering specific data from a  sheet, parse & filter it before listing it in a dataArray and append it to a html table.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

I've made a simple example of how to get data from several sheets and place in a custom dialog using just one function for each aspect.  I do not like the idea of using an event handler for loading data to a sheet and instead I prefer to use an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression `(function() {})();`

There are sheets name for each day of the week.  The callback function for google.script.run gets the data for the current day and the next day.

I think this should give you enough to start with.

[image]

The custom dialog for Monday shows the following

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("My Menu");
  menu.addItem("Test","showTest");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function showTest() {
  try {
    let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTML_Test');
    html = html.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Show Test");
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}

function getData(day) {
  try {
    console.log(day);
    let days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName(day);
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let data = {};
    data.today = values[1];
    sheet = days.indexOf(day)+1;
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName(days[sheet]);
    values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    data.tomorrow = values[1];
    return JSON.stringify(data);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Today is: <input id="dayofweek" type="text">
    <br>
    <table id="dataTable">
    </table>
    <script>
      (function() {
        try {
          let days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
          let today = new Date();
          today = today.getDay();
          document.getElementById("dayofweek").value = days[today];
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
            function(data) {
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              let table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
              let row = table.insertRow(0);
              let day = data.today;
              day.unshift("Today");
              day.forEach( (col,index) => { let cell = row.insertCell(index);
                                            cell.innerHTML = col.toString();
                                          }
                          );
              row = table.insertRow();
              day = data.tomorrow;
              day.unshift("Tomorrow");
              day.forEach( col => { let cell = row.insertCell();
                                    cell.innerHTML = col.toString();
                                  }
                          );
            }
          ).withFailureHandler( function (err) {
              alert(err);
            }
          ).getData(days[today]);
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Reference**

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)
- [JSON.stringify()/parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is absolutely correct, and yet my dumbass didn't take into consideration the multiple functions/handlers needing to use the same info to know where to look. Could you please look at this again.

Comment: Why so many functions?  The look like the all do the same thing.

Comment: Could be that I'm a novice, but I'm also not showing everything. I wrote this example for what I need, and to spare any help of looking too much into the unimportant. Each function is pulling a different set of coordinates/arrays from different areas of a large spreadsheet that acts as a schedule for our centers. We only want employees to see what pertains to them and not be bound to a paid google account just to view a spreadsheet. Pulling and filtering their info from this spreadsheet is easy enough, really, but writing the same function for each day of the week is excessive.

Comment: Each `google.script.run` is a call to the server for data.  They run asynchronously so no telling which one finishes first.  I would suggest merging into one `google.script.run` get all the data in one call.  Once it is in your client's memory use one function to seperate it.  So my example of one `google.script.run` call and one function in `<script>` would be the best solution.

Comment: I think I understand, but I can I still do this while calling different coordinates across different tabs? Also, each thing I call needs to be filtered and listed by different criteria. Could we possibly do a google meet, so that I may show you what is happening and know once and for if the suggested method can solve my issue?

Comment: I don't know how to do Google Meet.  What do I need to do?

Comment: I'll keep that link open for the next hour.

Comment: If you are still up to it, I'll open the link back up anytime.

Comment: Sorry you're going to have to help me.  I don't know what to do?

Comment: I posted a link to a virtual meet where I can share the project. Here is that same link again. https://meet.google.com/xoc-hpow-zgz

Comment: Thank you again for this. I'm not sure this is like our spreadsheet and app at all though. I will apply what I can though. I believe I'm just not sharing enough info, the reason being so much of the information is confidential. I assumed posting example functions and explaining the goal would suffice, but people are still asking questions outside what is posted above. So please, at any time, if you are still able to meet, I'm keeping the link above open all day. I think it'll help with understanding both the context and/or confines of my issue.

Comment: I would be willing to chat but a video meeting is not required.  I believe the example I have shown contains all the methods and techniques necessary to pull information from multiple sheets, multiple ranges into what I believe to be a custom dialog using HTMLService.  Duplicating google.script.run for each value, and duplicating functions for each day seems redundant.  I think if you study my example you will see how to adapt to your situration.

Comment: Fair enough. I do believe them to be redundant as well, and I will make do with what I can here. Your example though of sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); is gathering one set of data from columns 1-3. My problem requires multiple tables from the same sheet for each day, in different sections, not stacked side by side. So in this way I'm still having to repeat code to get all sections located on a page for each page. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think your stuck in a mindset that I can't get through.  I can get any value or number of values from any sheet or sheets using a single google.script.run, package it and send to the client dialog.  There I can unpack it and put it anywhere on the client dialog I want using a single function.

Comment: I believe so too, I'm not a guru here and won't pretend to be. I just have something that works, but I know can be better. I still don't understand how I can grab every unique section, being that some require different filters for the view --and still not have to multiply some code. But it's something, and I appreciate it. I'll just have to keep doing my homework. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Let see if this can explain how to do what you want in a single function rather than redundant functions.

Since I don't know what data you are getting and what you are doing with it I can't build a script that can do exactly what you want.  But if this is not enough to help you figure out how to get and set the data values you want, I don't know what more I can do.

[image]

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("My Menu");
  menu.addItem("Test","showTest");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function showTest() {
  try {
    let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTML_Test');
    html = html.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Show Test");
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}

function getData(day) {
  try {
    let days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName(day);
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    let data = {};
    data.date = values[1][1];
    data.shift = values[2][2];  // lets do night shift
    data.duration = values[3][2]
    data.naps = values[4][2]
    data.clean = values[5][2]
    data.support = values[6][2]
    data.client =values[7][1]
    return JSON.stringify(data);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Today is: <input id="dayofweek" type="text">
    <br>
    <table id="dataTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Date</td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shift</td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Duration</td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Naps</td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Clean</td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Support</td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Client</td><td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
      (function() {
        try {
          let days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
          let today = new Date();
          today = today.getDay();
          document.getElementById("dayofweek").value = days[today];
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
            function(data) {
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              let table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
              let row = table.rows[0];
              let cell = row.cells[1];
              cell.innerHTML = data.date;
              row = table.rows[1];
              cell = row.cells[1];
              cell.innerHTML = data.shift;
              row = table.rows[2];
              cell = row.cells[1];
              cell.innerHTML = data.duration;
              row = table.rows[3];
              cell = row.cells[1];
              cell.innerHTML = data.naps;
              row = table.rows[4];
              cell = row.cells[1];
              cell.innerHTML = data.clean;
              row = table.rows[5];
              cell = row.cells[1];
              cell.innerHTML = data.support;
              row = table.rows[6];
              cell = row.cells[1];
              cell.innerHTML = data.client;
            }
          ).withFailureHandler( function (err) {
              alert(err);
            }
          ).getData(days[today]);
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay I figured the one above out. Last problem is with "row.cells[]" is there a way to list more than one in a table. Most of the information are in chunks or small tables of 5 columns x 7 rows.

Comment: I added an example = "dataArray.forEach(function (r) " in my original post in the section "HTML_Test.html"

Comment: Also, we are missing one major variable. Filtering the information of (most but not all) sections by the signed in user. Each row in a particular days tab is listed by the the individual. We don't want others being able to see another's shift. Originally I used "var filteredData = data.filter(function (employee) { return employee[0]  === currentUser; })". This worked, but I don't know how to apply it to your model for specific sections/tables.  This issue still pending mapping an array/section across the html table. God I hope this makes sense.